# Angular2 - Decode JWT payload with Regex

Tags: regex, angular, base64, angular2-jwt

Trying to develop the access control of my application using JWT, I am following some suggestion I've found in the communities and I am encoding and decoding the token parts, through these two functions in the server side (PHP Restfull API):

```
static function base64Url_encode( $val ){
    return strtr(base64_encode( $val ), '+/=', '-_,');
}

static function base64Url_decode( $val ){
    return base64_decode( strtr($val , '+/=', '-_,') );
}
```

But from the client side (Angular2), I can't decode it and get the following error message:

```
Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.
```

After some searchng through the communities, I decided to do like this:

```
let encodedPayload = this.token.split('.')[1];
let payload = encodedPayload.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/,/g,'=');
```

And it works fine, but I am sure there is a better approach.

Is there a better solution to decode the returned string than nest replace function?

Comment: Isn't the answer in the question? What does "How should I decode the return?" mean?

Comment: I want a better solution than nested replaces like I did. I will edit my question.